# Extending Windows 7 system partition to the left

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, disk-space

I have an old pc with Windows 7 and Lubuntu dual-booted. Since I don't really use Lubuntu any more, I've wanted to get rid of it. Here's the problem: As you can see in this image:

[image: Screenshot of partitioning of hard drive.]

You can see that my Windows 7 partition is in the middle and not directly on the left. After looking around the internet a bit I've seen that this is a bit of a problem if you want to extend the middle partition. Still, my question is: **Is there still any consistent way of extending a middle partition to the left without losing data?**

I will take any suggestions. I'm fine with 3rd party software, as long as it's free.
By *consistent* I mean that the process won't cause errors sometimes.

I have seen a suggestion on the internet to copy all data to a secondary drive, and I can do that but *only* if there is no other option.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You will need a bootable partition editor, since the `C` partition cannot be moved
while Windows is running. I suggest using the
[AOMEI Partition Assistant Standard Edition Freeware](https://www.ubackup.com/free-partition.html)
and
[creating its Bootable CD/USB](https://www.diskpart.com/help/make-bootable-cd-wizard.html).

In case of a problem that will make Windows unbootable, you should also prepare
a boot installation USB for the latest version of Windows 10,
with which to do Startup Repair.

There is absolutely no guarantee that such a drastic process won't cause any errors.
I suggest before starting any partition work to take good backups,
since errors while changing partitions can destroy the disk,
up to taking a backup image of the disk
(a good product is
[AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.ubackup.com/free-backup-software.html)),
which also can create its boot CD/USB for emergency.

The procedure to follow:

- Boot the AOMEI Partition Assistant
- Delete the Lubuntu partition (the first one?) so it becomes unallocated space
- Move C to the left so the unallocated space now follows `C`
- Reboot Windows
- Use Device Manager to enlarge `C`

I note that a safer procedure would be to boot Windows and use Device Manager to
reformat the Lubuntu partition as NTFS and make it into your disk `D`.

Comment: Formatting the Lubuntu drive to NTFS would result in 2 different drives to show up, yes? Just making sure.

Comment: Yes. You may assign it a label and a drive-letter. If you are booting using GRUB, this will render the computer unbootable: Try in such a case the boot menu (usually F10/F12). Prepare an installation boot USB for Windows so in the worse case you can do Startup Repair.

Comment: Why would GRUB make the PC unbootable? GRUB shouldn't detect any OS on the secondary drive right?

Comment: This is if GRUB has files on the Lubuntu drive. But this is easily fixed by Startup Repair.